# Swift, awake function, how do I make sure this code is only called once?

Tags: swift, watchkit

In my controller, I have a button that reloads the controller with the following code, to hide the back button:

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["Record"], contexts: [], orientation: .vertical, pageIndex: 0)
```

When this code is triggered the `awake` function is called again. My `awake` function is as follows:

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    let track = context as! Track

    locationManager.trackMetaData = track

    //create new session
    sessionManager.createNewSession(track: locationManager.trackMetaData!)

    finishButton.setHidden(true)
}
```

The function `sessionManager.createNewSession` can only be called once, and the parameter required for this function requires the `context` parameter. How can I make sure this code is only called once? I could set a boolean variable in the `init()` function, and then check it hasn't already been executed int his one, but is that the right way to go about it?

Comment: just check to see if trackMetaData or sessionManager has already been defined - if it has, then return

Comment: Check if the class for sessionManager has some state property you can use for this or as you suggested yourself create and manage your own state property for the session